# I want to create a custom folder in the Application and services log area in windows event logs

Tags: powershell, logging, events

I am trying to create a custom folder in the Application and services log area in windows event logs.
Inside the folder I want to create two custom area’s ex: Area1, Area2. In Area1, I want to write the logs from one source and In Area2, I want to write logs from another source.
Original i want to do it using .net c# but as couldn't do it using c# so
I used powershell script to achieve this.

the code is below:

```
$PrimaryEventKey = 'Comp1'

$ApplicationName = 'App1'

$LogName = 'TSP'

$primarylocation = 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Channels'

$LogName = $PrimaryEventKey + '-' + $ApplicationName + '-' + $LogName

$EventRoot = (Join-Path $primarylocation $LogName)

if (!(Test-Path $EventRoot))
{
New-Item -Path ($secondarylocation + '/' + $Logname)

New-ItemProperty -Path ($secondarylocation + '/' + $Logname) -Name providerGuid -PropertyType String -Value "{$($GUID)}"

New-Item -Path $EventRoot

New-ItemProperty -Path $EventRoot -Name Enabled -PropertyType DWord -Value 1

New-ItemProperty -Path $EventRoot -Name Type -PropertyType DWord -Value 1

New-ItemProperty -Path $EventRoot -Name Isolation -PropertyType DWord -Value 0

New-ItemProperty -Path $EventRoot -Name RestrictGuestAccess -PropertyType String -Value 1

New-ItemProperty -Path $EventRoot -Name OwningPublisher -PropertyType String -Value "{$($GUID)}"
}
else
{
Write-Warning 'Event Log (Key) Already exists in registry'
}

Write into the event log (Example)

$eventType = ([System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType]::Information)

$evt = New-Object System.Diagnostics.EventLog($LogName)

$evt.Source = "SomeSource" 

$evt.WriteEntry("random message", $eventType, 60001)
```

By running this script I am able to create folder hierarchy but when I go to see the event logs It is showing error like:
**How to resolve this issue or is there any alternative approach to do it ?
Or any other way to create folder structure and then write logs in .net or through script ?**

please go through below image link to have a look towords issue.
[This is the image link click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Sev.png)

Comment: Why did you tag this as asp.net?

Comment: @mason I am trying this in my asp.net application.

Comment: This is PowerShell. Not ASP.NET.